# How to fetch data from firebase only 10 row at first time in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my android application i am fetching data from Firebase and displaying it in recyclerView. It is working fine but now i want that at first time only 10 rows should be fetched and when user scrolls recylerview then next 10 rows will be fetched. I am not understanding how to do it. I checked many question related this but couldn't link it with my code. Please check my code and tell me how can i do this.

```
arrayAdapter = new ContentViewRecyclerAdapter(contentname, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    String classname = getIntent().getStringExtra("classname");
    if(classname.equals("A")) {
       content = getIntent().getStringExtra("jokecontent");
       funnyJokesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes").orderByChild("subcategory")
               .equalTo(content);
       funnyJokesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
               String contentdisplay = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue(String.class);
               ContentModel contentModel = new ContentModel(contentdisplay);
               contentname.add(0,contentModel);
               arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

           }
           @Override
           public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


           }

           @Override
           public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only 10 child nodes you can use `limitToFirst(10)` in your query:

```
funnyJokesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes")
        .orderByChild("subcategory")
        .equalTo(content)
        .limitToFirst(10);
funnyJokesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    ...
```

To then get the next 10 items, you'll need to create a second query that starts at the last item of the previous page. This is because Firebase queries are based on cursors (a specific item) and not on offsets counts.

To track the anchor item, you could change your `onChildAdded` to:

```
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
           ...

           lastCategorySeen = dataSnapshot.child("subcategory").getValue(String.class);
           lastKeySeen = dataSnapshot.getKey();
       }
```

And then the query for the next page look like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes")
        .orderByChild("subcategory")
        .startAt(lastCategorySeen, lastKeySeen)
        .limitToFirst(11);
```

So the `startAt` here tells the database to start at the last item of the first page. We then retrieve 11 items, since the anchor item is present in both queries.

Note that this is a complex topic that has been covered extensively both on other sites and here. I recommend checking out some of the previous [questions on firebase and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination).

Comment: But i want next ten item should be fetched only on recyclerview's onscroll listener.

Comment: OK. So that means you'll have to put this second query inside that onscroll listener.

Comment: what is the type of lastcategoryseen and lastkeyseen...Means are they string ??

Comment: The `lastKeySeen` is a string, because keys in the database are strings. The `lastCategorySeen` is whatever type your `subcategory` property has, most likely also a string.

Comment: and what i have written in onchildadded() method...should i delete that ?

Comment: No, the `...` in my answer should be your original code. Since my answer is only about the query, I tried to include only code that is relevant to the query.

Comment: Okay, got it. But can you tell me where should i call recyclerview.onscrolllistener() method ?